# Border links vs backbone links

Tags: traffic

While reading an article about a traffic classification I came across these two terms, which were unfortunately not explained. It was just said that border links are more suitable for the host behavior classification than backbone links. Any idea what this could mean ?

Link to the article: [link](http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~dhiman/papers/conext_08.pdf)

> The best place to use BLINC is the border link of a single-homed edge
>   network, so BLINC can capture full (bidirectional) behavioral
>   information of the internal hosts. BLINC is not recommended for
>   backbone links (...)

Comment: Please consider linking to the article you're asking questions about, so people can see the context in which these terms were used.

Comment: ok, link is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commonly used, a border link is the point to point network between an organization and other, external networks.  The most common example is the link between a organization's network and an Internet service provider.

Backbone links are usually internal point to point links that make up the "core" of a network topology.

The authors are saying that the best place to monitor traffic (presumably in and out of your network) is on the border link.

I had not heard of BLINC (**BLIN**d **C**lassification) before, but [here is a good explanation](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~fabian/course_papers/BLINC.pdf).

> We present a fundamentally different approach to classifying traffic
>   flows according to the applications that generate them. In contrast to
>   previous methods, our approach is based on observing and identifying
>   patterns of host behavior at the transport layer.